# Apache Camel Dozer Expresison Mapping

Tags: java, apache-camel, dozer

I'm trying to map a class to another with Apache Camel and Dozer mapping.

Within my route I save an object of a class in a property, like `.setProperty("test", testClass)`. Now I want to get the class object out of this property and map it to a field of a new class.

The camel dozer documentation [Camel Dozer](http://camel.apache.org/dozer.html) says that it is possible to map an expression to a field. If I'm trying to map the value of the property to the corresponding field, I'm getting always `null` as value.

This is the way I'm trying to get the value of the property

```xml
<field custom-converter-id="_expressionMapping" custom-converter-param="simple:${exchangeProperty.test}">
    <a>expression</a>
    <b>targetField</b>
</field>
```

Is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, and looking at the documentation, you may just be missing  a '\' in front of the '$' sign:

```
<field custom-converter-id="_expressionMapping" 
    custom-converter-param="simple:\${exchangeProperty.test}">
  <a>expression</a>
  <b>targetField</b>
</field>
```

I think its even specifically mentioned at the very end of the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/dozer.html):

> Note that any properties within your expression must be escaped with "\" to prevent an error when Dozer attempts to resolve variable values defined using the EL.

Comment: I tried it with a "\", but it did not work. The same code works for other data types like integer or BigInteger. But if I use an object of a class, it does not work anymore.